# Is it possible to track new querys on DB?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, openvpn, pfsense

I'm searching for a new options all days and I'm making a new Word file with all the information I get but I can't reach a conclusion.

I'll explain the main idea.

My idea:
**User (Employee, client)** => **Firewall (VPN or Proxy)** => **Office Network**

What should I use?
**PFSense, Proxie, Ubuntu + OpenVPN or ??**

What I want to track/monitor?
**CLOUD - Local Machine with Address IP: 192.168.x.x**
**Database**

I want to monitor all the things they have done at our **cloud** and the *querys* or changes on **database**. And I want this changes and logs in one file or database.

Currently using AZURE and its a little bit hard for me to configure it right with pfsense.

Is it possible to structure something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use tcpdump, and store what you need in some log files.
To monitor queries to database you can use for example this script.
source -> https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/how-to-catch-mysql-sql-with-tcpdump-in-linux/maximized

```
#!/bin/bash
tcpdump -i your_network_interface_name -s 0 -l -w - dst port 3306 | strings | perl -e '
while(<>) { chomp; next if /^[^ ]+[ ]*$/;
    if(/^(SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT|SET|COMMIT|ROLLBACK|CREATE|DROP|ALTER|CALL)/i)
{
    if (defined $q) { print "$q\n"; }
    $q=$_;
} else {
    $_ =~ s/^[ \t]+//; $q.=" $_";
}
```

}'

You can even specify source and destination IP which you need to monitor.

Comment: Thats nice!! What about cloud?

Comment: Is there any option that I can add to that tcpdump to check what ip did what? Or name?

Comment: You can modify tcpdump command to listen only for specific IP address, like this  

      tcpdump -i your_interface -s 0 -l -w - host ip_address and dst port 3306

Comment: Hmm.. thats not bad. But I don't want a single address I want to monitor atleast 2 people that do querys everyday, how should I do that? And i'll run a script to keep executing that tcpdump every 24h

Comment: You can give them access via openvpn for example , where you can define for this two account specific local IP address on server. Then you will be able to identify them, and monitor this Ip . Openvpn can also be a trigger , if they will connect successful , then your script should start automatically, and keep logs peer account=Ip . :)